# How can i serialize and deserialize a dictionary in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, serialization, dictionary

I am working with an application that needs to store large dictionaries of 40 000+ keys and values in a file, and then load them back into dictionaries on startup... Right now i am using a simple character separation with split and a for each loop on startup like:
`key1=value1|key2=value2|key3=value3` etc...

however, i am looking for a more efficient way of serializing and deserializing the dictionaries... also with size of the serialized data in mind as there is quite a lot of entries.

Comment: Consider using a database.

Comment: I know a database would be preferred, but i was hoping for an alternative to php serialization of associative arrays for dictionaries.

Answer (score 4):

You could make use of `BinaryFormatter`
On my mid end machine: save took: 390ms load took: 359ms data saved was about 1500kb

```
'save
Dim dict = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
For i = 1 To 40000
    dict.Add("key" & i, "value" & i)
Next
Dim fs As IO.FileStream = New IO.FileStream("d:\test\test.bin", IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
Dim bf As New Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
bf.Serialize(fs, dict)
fs.Close()

'load
Dim fsRead As New IO.FileStream("d:\test\test.bin", IO.FileMode.Open)
Dim objTest As Dictionary(Of String, String) = bf.Deserialize(fsRead)
fsRead.Close()
```

Comment: Could this be stored as a string?

Comment: Afraid not, `BinaryFormatter` saves it as binary data, which makes for fairly fast access, not human readability, you could consider `XmlSerializer`, another standard or even manual Serialization.

Comment: What i do now is a form of manual serialization... i think binary serialization would be faster, the only reason i am asking is that i need to store multiple serialized dictionaries within the same file, thus i need a splitpoint to separate them on load...

Comment: Splitting them could of course be achived by appending strings at the end of the files indicating each individual dictionaries byte position within the larger file, and then use fseek to read from each of those points...

Comment: It turns out that this serialization takes about 4 times the space of my manual serialization... are there any methods that would use less space?...

Answer (score 0):

This works well when using stacked dictionaries:

```
Dim DataDict as New Dictionary(Of String,Dictionary(Of String,String))
```

Here is a working example of embedded dictionaries being serialized for writing and reading:

```
Imports System.IO
Module Modules
  Public Sub TestDict()
    Dim DictsToSave As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))
    For DictsToHave = 1 To 10
        Dim SingelDictData As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        For Values = 1 To 10000
            SingelDictData.Add("Key " & Values.ToString(), "Value " & Values.ToString())
        Next
        DictsToSave.Add("Key " & DictsToHave.ToString(), SingelDictData)
    Next
    Dim WriteResult = WriteMultiSerializedDict("D:\TestDict.Bin", DictsToSave)
    Dim ReadResult As Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String)) = ReadMultiSerializedDict("D:\TestDict.Bin")

End Sub
Public Function WriteMultiSerializedDict(ByVal FullPath As String, ByVal DataDict As Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim FileStream As IO.FileStream = New FileStream(FullPath, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
        Dim BinFormatter As New Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
        BinFormatter.Serialize(FileStream, DataDict)
        FileStream.Close()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
Public Function ReadMultiSerializedDict(ByVal FullPath As String) As Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))
    Try
        Dim DataDict As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))
        Dim FileStream As IO.FileStream = New FileStream(FullPath, IO.FileMode.Open)
        Dim BinFormatter As New Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
        DataDict = BinFormatter.Deserialize(FileStream)
        FileStream.Close()
        Return DataDict
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

On my mid end dev machine, this took about 260 ms for the write and 545 for the read, with a file that measured at 3.70 mb.  Important note:  If you change any of the dict's keys (not values), the load bombs!  So, as a matter of programming, always assemble your dicts in the same order.  I've used this approach before, using 5 100 key/value pairs in the sub dictionary's, without issue or problem.